# Why we don't have HTML 3

Tags: html, versioning

I know this question is quite weird
I was going through history of HTML and saw there HTML 1,HTML 2, HTML 4 and HTML 5
 I goggled on same thing but it resulted nothing (Might be CSS release in year 1996 was considered as HTML 3)
Any comments regarding HTML 3 will be really appreciated.

Comment: There is html3 also.. [Quick Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

Comment: I think you didn't google properly.

Comment: yeah didn't read that long article of wikipedia

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history and speculation, not practical problems.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there was Html 3.2:

> January 1997
>   HTML 3.2[13] was published as a W3C Recommendation. It was the first version developed and standardized exclusively by the W3C, as the IETF had closed its HTML Working Group in September 1996.[14]
>   Initially code-named "Wilbur",[15] HTML 3.2 dropped math formulas entirely, reconciled overlap among various proprietary extensions and adopted most of Netscape's visual markup tags. Netscape's blink element and Microsoft's marquee element were omitted due to a mutual agreement between the two companies.[12] A markup for mathematical formulas similar to that in HTML was not standardized until 14 months later in MathML.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html#Version_history_of_HTML

The wikipedia article explains the version history fairly thoroughly.

Comment: then why this HTML 3.2 was depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There was an HTML 3. It was replaced by HTML 4 in 1997.

Answer (score 2):

## March 1995: HTML 3 is published as an Internet Draft

> Dave Raggett had been working for some time on his new ideas for HTML, and at last he formalized them in a document published as an Internet Draft in March, 1995. All manner of HTML features were covered. A new tag for inserting images called FIG was introduced, which Dave hoped would supersede IMG, as well as a whole gambit of features for marking up math and scientific documents. Dave dealt with HTML tables and tabs, footnotes and forms. He also added support for style sheets by including a STYLE tag and a CLASS attribute. The latter was to be available on every element to encourage authors to give HTML elements styles, much as you do in desktop publishing.
>
> Although the HTML 3 draft was very well received, it was somewhat difficult to get it ratified by the IETF. The belief was that the draft was too large and too full of new proposals. To get consensus on a draft 150 pages long and about which everyone wanted to voice an opinion was optimistic - to say the least. In the end, Dave and the inner circle of the HTML community decided to call it a day.
>
> Of course, browser writers were very keen on supporting HTML 3 - in theory. Inevitably, each browser writer chose to implement a different subset of HTML 3's features as they were so inclined, and then proudly proclaimed to support the standard. The confusion was mind-boggling, especially as browsers even came out with extensions to HTML 3, implying to the ordinary gent that normal HTML 3 was, of course, already supported. Was there an official HTML 3 standard or not? The truth was that there was not, but reading the computer press you might never have known the difference.

[source](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML 3.0 Overview** - **Official Documentation(w3c.org)**

> HTML has been in use by the World-Wide Web (WWW) global information
>   initiative since 1990. The HTML 3.0 specification provides a number of
>   new features, and is broadly backwards compatible with HTML 2.0. It is
>   defined as an application of International Standard ISO ISO8879:1986
>   Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML). This specificiation will
>   be proposed as the Internet Media Type (RFC 1590) and MIME Content
>   Type (RFC 1521) called "text/html; version=3.0"

More Details Here [HTML 3.0 - W3C>>](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML3 was released in March 1995. See a [history of HTML](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html).

Answer (score 0):

January 1997
HTML 3.2 was published as a W3C Recommendation. It was the first version developed and standardized exclusively by the W3C, as the IETF had closed its HTML Working Group in September 1996.
Initially code-named "Wilbur", HTML 3.2 dropped math formulas entirely, reconciled overlap among various proprietary extensions and adopted most of Netscape's visual markup tags. Netscape's blink element and Microsoft's marquee element were omitted due to a mutual agreement between the two companies. A markup for mathematical formulas similar to that in HTML was not standardized until 14 months later in MathML.
Source : **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Version_history_of_HTML)**